How do I convert a JSON inner array to an array of objects?
I have tried the following code:
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content!);
var jsonArray = result.items;
var arrayEvents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VanEvent[]>(jsonArray);

To get an array of the objects in this JSON (response.Content):
{
  "items": [
    {
      "eventId": 408936,
      "name": "Door to door",
      "shortName": "door",
      "description": "walking the beat",
      "startDate": "2024-04-17T12:00:00-06:00",
      "endDate": "2024-04-17T15:30:00-06:00",
      "eventType": {
        "eventTypeId": 659466,
        "name": "Canvassing"
      },
      "isOnlyEditableByCreatingUser": false,
      "isPubliclyViewable": null,
      "locations": [],
      "codes": [],
      "notes": [],
      "shifts": [
        {
          "eventShiftId": 461796,
          "name": "Single Shift",
          "startTime": "2024-04-17T12:00:00-06:00",
          "endTime": "2024-04-17T15:30:00-06:00"
        }
      ],
      "roles": [
        {
          "roleId": 567170,
          "name": "Organizer",
          "isEventLead": false,
          "min": null,
          "max": null,
          "goal": null
        },
        {
          "roleId": 567171,
          "name": "Volunteer",
          "isEventLead": false,
          "min": null,
          "max": null,
          "goal": null
        }
      ],
      "ticketCategories": null,
      "voterRegistrationBatches": null,
      "createdDate": "2024-04-15T16:57:00Z",
      "districtFieldValue": null,
      "financialProgram": null,
      "isActive": true,
      "dotNetTimeZoneId": "Mountain Standard Time"
    },
    {
      "eventId": 422483,
      // ...

But the call to DeserializeObject() is throwing a RuntimeBinderException with a message of:
The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ThirdPartyServices.VAN.VanEvent[]>(string)' has some invalid arguments

Why? This is passing in the array of these objects. And yes, VanEvent has a parameterless constructor.

I think you are getting this error because JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>() expects a string, but you are passing it an object from the previous deserialization, probably a JArray.
Try this instead:
var result = JObject.Parse(response.Content!);
var arrayEvents = result["items"].ToObject<VanItem[]>();


That was it - thank you. ps - dynamic is often your friend but sometimes it allows doing things that strict type checking would flag.

Exactly.  I usually try to avoid dynamic unless I'm working on throwaway code.

@BrianRogers I had the same opinion about dynamic for a long time until I started working with serializing/deserializing JSON data structures that could carry payloads that could by any disparate type.  I found dynamic to be a very useful solution to allowing whatever payload you needed, and it works almost seamlessly in client/server apps using ASP.NET Core with a JS or TS front-end.  The payloads just "work"--they deserialize automatically and, if needed, can be cast as an interface defined on the client side with ease.  To me it was too tempting a use case to continue to spurn dynamic

@BrianRogers also, see my comment here (though it was never answered).  In my opinion, it's a nifty usage of dynamic to get around an annoying issue with serialization and polymorphism.
